# Is Obama worth 30 times more than when he entered the White House?

Tags: barack-obama

This [article by Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/barack-obama-michelle-obama-net-worth-2018-7?IR=T), from 2019, states that "[the Obamas are] worth 30 times more than when they entered the White House in 2008".

Is it true? Is it normal?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107665/discussion-on-question-by-gelu-is-obama-worth-30-times-more-than-when-he-entered).

Comment: Not really a claim to be skeptical of. Former presidents' celebrity is very lucrative.

Comment: Note that 30 times more is not very meaningful because it primarly depends on the starting value, not the money earned in the time period. If Trump would be worth twice as much after his presidency that before that would be a lot more noteworthy than the Obama claim, simply because his so much higher starting wealth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_the_United_States_by_net_worth) puts Obama's *peak* net worth at 40 million, using 2016 U.S. dollars.

Wikipedia references A 2017 article in [al.com](https://www.al.com/news/2017/01/donald_trumps_net_worth_as_he.html) that claims that

> Obama's net worth, according to [GoBankingRates.com](https://www.gobankingrates.com/net-worth/politicians/barack-obama-net-worth/), is about $12.2 million. First Lady Michelle Obama's net worth is about $11.8 million.

Here is a quote about the finances of Barack Obama from an [2020 Fact Check article](https://www.factcheck.org/2020/02/accounting-for-net-worth-of-trump-clintons-and-obamas/) discussing a rumor about their finances:

> For Barack and Michelle Obama, $15.6 million of the $20.5 million that they earned between 2005 and 2016 came from books written by the former president, according to a 2017 Forbes analysis. Two of the books, “The Audacity of Hope” and “Dreams from My Father,” were published before he became president, and a third book for children was published in 2010. Just over $3 million came from the presidential salary for eight years.
>
> Since leaving the White House, Barack and Michelle Obama have signed onto high-profile deals, including one reportedly worth $60 million for a pair of memoirs. The first, written by Michelle Obama, was released in November 2018 and became the best-selling book that year. The couple also signed a television series and movie production deal with Netflix, but the amount they’ll make from it isn’t clear. One early report described it as a “high 8-figure deal.”

Comment: Speculative calculations are not welcome here.